# app.use(express.raw()) not working in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making an Express application that takes in (binary) post data. Here is my code below.

Server-side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.raw());
    
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on port", PORT);
});
```

index.html:

```html
<script>
  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: "hello world",
  });
</script>
```

However, when I run this code, when logging the request body, it logs an empty object. And when I looked at the documentation, it says that the request body will be an empty object if there was no body to parse. But I had a body in the request. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express.raw()` only works if you set your `Content-Type` header in your fetch to `application/octet stream. So your new fetch method would look like this.

```
fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: "hello world",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    }
});
```

But what if you don't want the content type to be `application/octet-stream`? In this case, you can specify in the `express.raw()` options that the content type to parse the body can be any type. How to do this? Replace this:

```
app.use(express.raw());
```

With this:

```
app.use(express.raw({type: '*/*'}));
```

The `type` option is the needed content type for `body-parser` to parse the body, and the `*/*` means that any content type will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

For `express.raw()` to parse, add `"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"` inside `headers` in your `fetch()`. Like so:

```js
fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  body: "hello world",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your usecase
`app.use(express.text());`

Comment: Works, but I guess I forgot to say the post data might be binary...

Comment: Look here: https://thewebdev.info/2022/02/28/how-to-get-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request/